# Action of the endomorphism ring of a module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a ring with $1$ and $M$ a left $A$-module. In chapter 6 of Curtis and Reiner's 'Methods of Representation theory', $M$ is regarded as a right module over the endomorphism ring $E=\text{End}_A(M)$ of $M$.

I'm confused how $M$ can become a right $E$-module as the only $E$-action on $M$ I can think of is by $E$ acting as left operators on $M$ making it a left $E$-module.

I must be overlooking something trivial here.

Comment: That action you can think of is not a *left* action... Just try to check its associativity and watch it fail.

Comment: Well, if we write composition of endomorphisms from right to left, I think we indeed have to take the opposite ring $E^{op}$ for the right action.

Comment: @ Mariano Sorry what I meant was the mapping $E\times M \to M$ in the definition of a left $E$-module. By the way, shouldn't composition of mappings always be associative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know the book by Curtis and Reiner, but a well-established convention in ring and module theory is to write morphisms on the opposite side to the scalars and probably the book uses it.

This avoids awkward references to the opposite ring that pop out when morphisms are written on the same side.

So, if left module are considered, morphisms are written on the right and composition of maps reflects this: so, for $f\colon L\to M$ and $g\colon M\to N$, the composition is $fg$
$$
(x)fg=((x)f)g
$$
for $x\in L$.

This has the consequence that a left $A$-module is in a natural way a *right* module over the endomorphism ring $B=\operatorname{End}({}_AM)$ of $_AM$.

The natural map $A\to\operatorname{End}(M_B)$ is a ring homomorphism; it is defined by $a\mapsto \hat{a}$, where $\hat{a}(x)=ax$.
This is indeed an endomorphism of $M_B$, because, for $b\in B$,
$$
\hat{a}(xb)=a((x)b)=(ax)b=(\hat{a}(x))b
$$
(the middle equality is because $b\in\operatorname{End}({}_AM)$).

In particular, $M$ becomes an $A$-$B$-bimodule.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Comment: Is it fair to say that the reason to consider morphisms as acting on the right is so that we can write post-composition of functions from left to right in the way that we might read English?

Comment: @tekay-squared Not really. This is to avoid having to use the opposite ring in several places. Morphisms of right modules are written on the left, of left modules on the right (with reverse conventions on composition).

Answer (score 2):

To obtain a right module $M_E$ we (implicitly) have to switch the direction of the operation of $E$, i.e. have to interpret composition of endomorphisms from left to right. This way, with the original left action ${}_AM$, we get a *bimodule* ${}_AM_E$ as the connecting axiom
$$(am)\varphi=a(m\varphi)$$
follows from $\varphi$ being an $A$-module homomorphism.