# Endomorphism ring of a simple module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $D$ be a division ring, and $R=M_n(D)$, the ring of $n\times n$ matrices over $D$. Let 
$$V=\begin{Bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} D & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
D & 0 & \cdots & 0\\\end{bmatrix}\end{Bmatrix}$$ be the subset of $R$ consisting of matrices with $2$nd, $3$rd, .. $n$th columns zero.

Then $V$ is a *left* simple $R$-module (in fact, $R$ has, up to isomorphism, a unique simple left $R$-module).

Consider $\operatorname{End}(_RV)$, the ring of endomorphisms of the left $R$-module $V$.

In the book *A First Course in Non-commutative Rings by Lam*, author asserts (see p.33)

> (3) The endomorphism ring $\operatorname{End}(_RV)$, viewed as a ring of right operators on $V$, is isomorphic to $D$.

**Q.** The statement of (3) is concerning isomorphism of rings; but then, what is the need to consider the former ring to be ring of *right operators* on $V$?

In answer to a similar question [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319141/action-of-the-endomorphism-ring-of-a-module), it is mentioned that *This (writing endomorphisms of left module to right side) avoids awkward references to the opposite ring that pop out when morphisms are written on the same side.*

I didn't understand how does, after writing endomorphisms of left module to left side, pops up opposite ring?

---

I just thought following lines: see if this is correct, which shows some arrival of opposite ring

$V$ is simple left $R$-module, hence it is generated (as $R$-module) by single element, say $v$. Then for any $f\in \operatorname{End}(_RV)$,

(i) $f$ is completely determined by effect on $v$;

(ii) $f(v)=r_f v$ for some $r_f\in R$.

So, if $g$ is another $R$-endomorphism of $V$, then, with convention of writing endomorphisms on left side, we have 
$$(f g)(v)=f(g(v))=f(r_g v)=r_g(f(v))=r_gr_fv \mbox{ and } (fg)(v)=r_{fg}(v).$$

Since $R$ is simple ring and $V$ is simple $R$-module, so left-annihilator of $v$ is $0$. Thus, from $r_{fg}v=r_gr_f v$ we get $r_{fg}=r_gr_f$. This could be the place of opposite ring to come in picture. Is this right?

Comment: There is a simpler explanation, maybe: you want End(V) to  be an $R$-module, which is not if you take left operators (because $R$ is not commutative)

Comment: @GreginGre I don’t get it, nowhere is any $R$-module structure of $\operatorname{End}_R V$ mentioned or used, right?

Comment: @beginner I think you misunderstood. If you start with a simple right $R$ module $V$ and view $End(V_R)$ as operating on the left of $V$, then you get a division ring, but it is actually the opposite of a division ring you are interested in.  Where you write the operator is immaterial to the structure of the endomorphism ring, but it is significantly more intuitive to put it opposite the action of the module.  Starting with a left vs a right module, though, *is* significant for the resulting endomorphism ring.

Comment: @rschweib: Can you explain a little the statement  ("*If you start with a simple right $R$-module $V$ and view $End(V_R)$ operating on the left of $V$, then you get a division ring, but it is actually opposite of a division ring you are interested in.*")?